# Android how to rotate an image file stored in SD card?

Tags: android, image, file, rotation, android-sdcard

Is it possible to rotate by 90 degrees a file stored in a known path to sd card without load it in memory?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to rotate by 90 degrees a file stored in a known path to sd card without load it in memory?

No. You cannot do anything with the contents of a file without loading those contents into memory. This holds true for any file in any file format.